# ¿Como imprimir una tabla y cuadrarla a través de javascript con etiquetas html?

Tags: javascript, html

Como pone en el titulo tengo un formulario que recoge una serie de datos y los imprime a través de una ventana, la cosa es que quiero que aparezcan en una tabla en la nueva ventana que se genera pero no soy capaz de poner bien las etiquetas html en javascript para hacer que se genere correctamente la tabla, debido a que el codigo es muy largo paso la parte que quiero imprimir por pantalla en otra ventana con sus correspondientes etiquetas html que llevo hasta el momento.

```
function mostrar() {
    debugger;
    console.log(dataCliente);
    var cliente = dataCliente;

    if (cliente) {
        var configuracion = "left=400,top=400,width=400,height=400";
        ventana = window.open("", "nombre ventana", configuracion);
        window.name = "ventana";
        var almacen = "<html><body><head><title>Cliente</title></head><table style='width:100% '>";
        almacen += "<tr><th>Nombre</th></tr><td> " + cliente.getNombre() + "</td>";
        almacen += "<tr><th>Codigo</th></tr><td> " + cliente.getCodigoPostal() + "</td>";
        almacen += "<tr><th>Localidad</th></tr><td> " + cliente.getLocalidad() + "</td>";
        almacen += "<tr><th>Nombre de la calle</th></tr><td> " + cliente.gettipovia() + "</td>";
        almacen += "<tr><th>Numero del portal</th></tr><td> " + cliente.getnumero()+ "</td>";
        almacen += "<tr><th>Telefono</th></tr><td> " + cliente.gettelef()+ "</td>";
        almacen += "<tr><th>Nombre de la mascota</th></tr><td> " + cliente.getnombremascota()+ "</td>";
        almacen += "<tr><th>Fecha de la masctoa</th></tr><td> " + cliente.getedadmascota()+ "</td>";
        almacen += "<tr><th>Descripcion</th></tr><td> "+ cliente.getdescripcion() +"</td>"
        almacen += "</table></body></html>"
        ventana.document.write(almacen);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En los elementos `table`, la jerarquía es la siguiente: dentro de cada `<tr>` van los `<td>` (filas normales, que pueden ser varias) o los `<th>` (fila para los encabezados, que se pone una sola vez, al principio).

Lo que estás haciendo es muy confuso y erróneo desde el punto de vista html.

Así debería funcionar, salvo otros errores:

```
function mostrar() {
    debugger;
    console.log(dataCliente);
    var cliente = dataCliente;

    if (cliente) {
        var configuracion = "left=400,top=400,width=400,height=400";
        ventana = window.open("", "nombre ventana", configuracion);
        window.name = "ventana";
        var almacen = "<html><body><head><title>Cliente</title></head><table style='width:100% '>";
        /*Primero los encabezados con th, en un tr*/
        almacen += "<tr>";
        almacen += "<th>Nombre</th>";
        almacen += "<th>Codigo</th>";
        almacen += "<th>Localidad</th>";
        almacen += "<th>Nombre de la calle</th>";
        almacen += "<th>Numero del portal</th>";
        almacen += "<th>Telefono</th>";
        almacen += "<th>Nombre de la mascota</th>";
        almacen += "<th>Fecha de la mascota</th>";
        almacen += "<th>Descripcion</th>";
        almacen += "</tr>";
        /*Ahora cada fila con td, dentro de un tr*/
        almacen += "<tr>";
        almacen += "<td>"+cliente.getNombre()+"</td>";
        almacen += "<td>"+cliente.getCodigoPostal()+"</td>";
        almacen += "<td>"+cliente.getLocalidad()+"</td>";
        almacen += "<td>"+cliente.gettipovia()+"</td>";
        almacen += "<td>"+cliente.getnumero()+"</td>";
        almacen += "<td>"+cliente.gettelef()+"</td>";
        almacen += "<td>"+cliente.getnombremascota()+"</td>";
        almacen += "<td>"+cliente.getedadmascota()+"</td>";
        almacen += "<td>"+cliente.getdescripcion()+"</td>";
        almacen += "</tr>";
        almacen += "</table></body></html>"
        ventana.document.write(almacen);
}
```

[Revisa los ejemplos de tabla aquí para más detalles.](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)

#### Post-Data

A partir de ES6, puedes usar [*Plantillas literales*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), para escribir un código más claro, sin tantas concatenaciones.

Usando plantillas literales, esto:

```
        almacen += "<td>"+cliente.getNombre()+"</td>";
```

Se puede escribir así:

```
        almacen += `<td>${cliente.getNombre()}</td>`;
```

Como ves, no se usa `+` para concatenar cada parte. Hay otras técnicas si quieres concatenar todo el contenido de `almacen` dentro de un solo bloque, pero éstas podrían tener consecuencias si posteriormente quieres ofuscar tu código.